# About fixed point iterations

Tags: numerical-methods

I've read that to insure that a function $g(x)\in C[a,b]$ has a unique fixed point ,is to prove that the absolute values of its derivative $g^{'}(x); x\in]a,b[$ must be less than $1$.
what does this concept mean in analysis?

Comment: i think the thing you read is false. e.g. $g \in C[1,2]$, $g(x) = 0$ for $x \in [1,2]$.

Comment: What does "is to prove" mean? Grammatically, this makes no sense. To which concept are you referring? Is it concept of proof, the property of having a derivative bounded by unity, the property of having a unique fixed point or something else?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

This theorem gives the conditions for a unique fixed point of a function